# How Does ActionDescriptorProviderContext Get Results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

In 
 **Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Conventions.DefaultODataRoutingConvention.SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)**, my Controller class don't appear in IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider requiredService = **routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService();**

My assembly which contains the above class is located in the same bin folder.
This causes the "No Action Match Template" issue even though there is actually a code (a controller class together with its method) for that.

I found out the issue is caused by the missing item (which is my controller class) in the object **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionDescriptorCollection.Items** that is called by the previous line **routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService();**.

```
...
      string str3 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2) ? str1 + "/" + str2 : str1;
      //below is the problematic part
      IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider requiredService = routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();
      List<ActionDescriptor> actionDescriptorList = new List<ActionDescriptor>();
      ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor1 = (ActionDescriptor) null;
      foreach (ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor2 in requiredService.ActionDescriptors.Items.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>())
      {...
```

Because the property Items is assigned in the constructor of **ActionDescriptorCollection** which receives the parameter **IReadOnlyList items**, I also tried to find how does the constructor is called.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class ActionDescriptorCollection
    {
        public ActionDescriptorCollection(IReadOnlyList<ActionDescriptor> items, int version)
        {
            if (items == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
            }
            this.<Items>k__BackingField = items;
            this.<Version>k__BackingField = version;
        }
```

Based on the stack trace, it is called by the method **UpdateCollection()**  from **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider** in the line **_collection = new ActionDescriptorCollection(
                new ReadOnlyCollection(*context.Results*),
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _version));**

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default implementation of <see cref="IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class ActionDescriptorCollectionProvider : IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider
    {
...
        private void UpdateCollection()
        {
            var context = new ActionDescriptorProviderContext();

            for (var i = 0; i < _actionDescriptorProviders.Length; i++)
            {
                _actionDescriptorProviders[i].OnProvidersExecuting(context);
            }

            for (var i = _actionDescriptorProviders.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                _actionDescriptorProviders[i].OnProvidersExecuted(context);
            }

            _collection = new ActionDescriptorCollection(
                new ReadOnlyCollection<ActionDescriptor>(context.Results),
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _version));
        }
    }
}
```

The ***context.Results* is the ActionDescriptorProviderContext.Results**

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions
{
    public class ActionDescriptorProviderContext
    {
        public IList<ActionDescriptor> Results
        {
            [CompilerGenerated]
            get
            {
                return this.<Results>k__BackingField;
            }
        }

        public ActionDescriptorProviderContext()
        {
            this.<Results>k__BackingField = new List<ActionDescriptor>();
            base..ctor();
        }
    }
}
```

From this point, how is the Results populated with value?
I would expect to see the class from an assembly which is in the bin folder together.

Comment: Why are you digging into framework code? What problem are you trying to solve? Do you properly register the desired classes or assembly with the DI container, if that's what your question is about?

Comment: Actually I have 2 projects, one is working and another one is not.
Could you please let me know (1) how to check if I have already registered the class and (2) how to register it?
I checked the MSDN post on Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core where it says "Registration of the dependency in a service container. ASP.NET Core provides a built-in service container, IServiceProvider. Services are registered in the app's Startup.ConfigureServices method."

but the methods Startup.ConfigureServices in both solutions are the same